# How to access javascript result in selenium

Tags: javascript, python, html, function, selenium

I use below code to execute javascript, and it works well.

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver=webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("https:example.com")
driver.execute_script('isLogin()')
```

But when I try to access the result return by `isLogin()` with

```
isLogin = driver.execute_script('isLogin()')
print(isLogin)    # always None
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to return the value returned by `isLogin()`

```
isLogin = driver.execute_script('return isLogin();')
```